Define section to have hanging indents
I'm attempting to layout a short stay play, using the sides class which I've customized a bit. I'd like to indent lines after the first line by 100pt and struggling to do that. My tweaked class is here.
Dialogue is defined by the repl command as follows:
\newcommand{\repldef}{\@startsection {diag}{2}{0pt}%
    {0.8em} % space before name
    {0.0em} % space after name
    {%
       % I've unsuccessfully tried setting \hangindent here, etc.
       \scshape\normalsize\makebox[100pt][l]
    }%
}
\newcommand{\repl}{\repldef*}

Formatting timeless dialogue such as this:
\repl{Andi}
Yeah difficult to believe, but we've talked about it.

\repl{Gresham}
Yeah, yeah. Who hasn't talked about it. A few drinks in we've all
spouted. Throw it in, we say, give it up, that sort of stuff. But its
just the drink, innit. Natural frustration behind it. And we all
know -- what's the alternative? It's no better, is it?

produces output as follows:

I'd be very grateful for pointers on how to indent lines following the first line of dialogue by 100pt.

You want to increase the global left margin by 100pt and set the titles in the margin.

@egreg : thank you for your note. I guess I'd then have to make all the other commands be set 100pt to the left of the global margin. Would it not be easier to address any \par following this sort of \section?

Actually that worked fine, @egreg. Thanks!

Following @egreg's suggestion I simply increased the left margin by n and moved all the environments to be left indented by -n.
repldef ended up like this (with an n of 2cm):
\newcommand{\repldef}{\@startsection {diag}{2}{-2cm}%
    {0.8em} % space before name
    {0.0em} % space after name
    { %
      \scshape\normalsize\makebox[-3pt][l] %
    } %
}

(I had to fiddle with the makebox width by eye.)
